# Use CAPICOM in Server Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a code in .net for sign in client side and verify in server side.

And I must convert my code in asp classic.

In .net code on client side I sign with capicom by javascript.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Some needed constants
CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE = 2;
CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_READ_ONLY = 0;
CAPICOM_AUTHENTICATED_ATTRIBUTE_SIGNING_TIME = 0;
CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64 = 0;
function Authenticate() {
try {
var challenge = document.getElementById("<%=hid_Challenge.ClientID %>");
var response = document.getElementById("<%=hid_Response.ClientID %>");

// Open windows certificate store
var store = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.Store");
store.Open(CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE, "My", CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_READ_ONLY);

// Show personal certificates which are installed for this user
var certificates = store.Certificates.Select("KeyA3 Sample PKI Authentication", "Please select a certificate to authenticate.");

// Proceed if any certificate is selected
if (certificates.Count > 0) {
var signer = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.Signer");
signer.Certificate = certificates.Item(1);

var timeAttrib = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.Attribute");
timeAttrib.Name = CAPICOM_AUTHENTICATED_ATTRIBUTE_SIGNING_TIME;
var date = new Date('<%=DateTime.Now.ToString("F", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")) %>');
timeAttrib.Value = date.getVarDate();
signer.AuthenticatedAttributes.Add(timeAttrib);

var signedData = new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.SignedData");
signedData.Content = challenge.value;
response.value = signedData.Sign(signer, true, CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64);

return true;
}
return false;
}
catch (e) {
alert(e.description);
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

And

I check signed data in this code:

```
Byte[] signedData;
ContentInfo content;
SignedCms signed;

if (hid_Response.Value == null)
throw new ArgumentNullException("Response");

signedData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Session["Challenge"].ToString());
content = new ContentInfo(signedData);

signed = new SignedCms(content, true);
signed.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(hid_Response.Value));

// Set the parameter to 'true' if you want the certificate not be checked. 
signed.CheckSignature(true);

// Do further authentication and user mapping here.
// For example you could check some certificate parameters against your database.
// Here we only show the certificate information. Nothing checked here.
lbl_Message1.Text = "Authenticated successfully.";
lbl_Message1.Visible = true;

Dictionary<String, String> certProps = new Dictionary<String, String>();
certProps.Add("Subject", signed.Certificates[0].Subject);
certProps.Add("Issuer", signed.Certificates[0].Issuer);
certProps.Add("Valid From", signed.Certificates[0].NotBefore.ToString());
certProps.Add("Valid To", signed.Certificates[0].NotAfter.ToString());
certProps.Add("Friendly Name", signed.Certificates[0].FriendlyName);
certProps.Add("Version", signed.Certificates[0].Version.ToString());
certProps.Add("Serial Number", signed.Certificates[0].SerialNumber);
certProps.Add("Thumbprint", signed.Certificates[0].Thumbprint);
gvCertificate.DataSource = certProps;
gvCertificate.DataBind();
gvCertificate.Visible = true;
```

But I must run this code in asp classic

I successfully sign my data in client side by javascript.

And I want to verify data in server side by VBSCRIPT OR JAVASCRIPT.

Is any way?

Thanks

Comment: This makes a bit more sense of your last question, where I wasn't sure where the data for the dictionary object was coming from.The server side equivalent of new ActiveXObject() is Server.CreateObject().  This applies to both vbs and server side js.  I've never used CAPICOM before, and it looks like it may not be installed on newer versions of IIS, but I suggest you google 'Server.CreateObject("CAPICOM.Store")'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer.

It will be helpful.

```
Dim verification
Set verification = Server.CreateObject("CAPICOM.SignedData")
verification.Verify signed_Data, false, 0
For Each Certificate In verification.Certificates
    subject = Certificate.SubjectName
Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    result =  Err.Description &  Hex(Err.Number)
Else
    result = "Signature is OK"
End If
```